# How can you block multiple requests from same IP to Wowza Streaming Engine at a time?

Tags: java, streaming, video-streaming, wowza, wowza-transcoder

We have a Stream published in our Wowza Streaming Engine. We want that one user may access our stream once at a time. That means, he might not access our stream from many VLC player instances at a time! So, we need to block multiple access from one IP adress! How can we make the restriction in server? Is there any configuration to do in server to make it happen?

We used Hash generated security token to make unique url for every user session. But in the specific session time, user can access the url as much as he wants from many VLC player instances! How can we restrict it?

Answer (score 0):

I would [proxy the server through Apache](http://www.keendevelopment.ch/running-apache-and-wowzaflash-media-serverred5-on-port-80-at-the-same-time/) and [implement the limit in Apache](http://dominia.org/djao/limitipconn.html).